# Error: call revert exception // npm run dev

Tags: node.js, solidity, npx, hardhat

Steps: \

- npx hardhat node \
- (new terminal) npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deploy.js
  *Blog deploys correctly*\

When entering npm run dev this error appears:

error - Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="fetchPosts()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.0)

I've tested that I'm on the correct network but can't seem to work around this.

Comment: What is the value of the dev cmd in your `package.json`?

Comment: "dev": "next dev"

Answer (score 1):

This error (CALL_EXCEPTION) happens when your smart contract is not deployed yet.

Wait the transaction ends:

> await contract.deployTransaction.wait()

Comment: Where am I inserting this? in my deploy.js file?

Comment: npx hardhat run deploys correctly and I get an address where the blog is deployed